# How to create a Prediction Model in Python R style using multiple categorical variables

Tags: python, r, machine-learning, model, prediction

Do you know how to create a Prediction Model for Ensemble methods Classifiers in particular which are R style:

```
ded.fit(formula="X ~ Y + Z**2", data=fed)
```

Currently the Code looks something like this:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, min_samples_leaf=10,    
random_state=1)
model.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

A Question you may ask as to why I need this?

1. I need this to add more variables not just X and Y I need Z and P and Q and R as well.
2. I need to see and experiment like I do in R if adding an exponent or multiplying or dividing a value to a particular variable increases or decreases the accuracy of prediction like the formula below:

   `X ~ Y + Z^2" or "X ~ Y + Z + (P*2) + Q**2`

Any answers would be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Scikit-learn doesn't have any formula-style interface.  You can have multiple predictors by including them as columns in your X data.

Comment: Thanks @BrenBarn Could you please give an example it would really help on how to include multiple columns do we need to do this while splitting into X_Train and Y_Train?

Comment: There are tons of scikit learn tutorials and questions out there showing how to do it.  Look around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following should work:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
X = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 2)), columns=list('XZ'))
y = np.random.randint(2,size=100) # labels for binary classification
X['Z2'] = X.Z**2    # add more features
print X.head() # note the added feature Z^2
#    X   Z    Z2
#0  88  90  8100
#1  49  63  3969
#2  27  23   529
#3  47  71  5041
#4  21  98  9604
train_samples = 80  # Samples used for training the models
X_train = X[:train_samples]
X_test = X[train_samples:]
y_train = y[:train_samples]
y_test = y[train_samples:]
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from pandas_ml import ConfusionMatrix
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, min_samples_leaf=10, random_state=1)
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
#print confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
cm = ConfusionMatrix(y_test, y_pred)
print cm
# Predicted  0   1  __all__
# Actual
# 0          3   4        7
# 1          4   9       13
# __all__    7  13       20
cm.plot()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I want to retain the columns not merge them into another one this is not the answer I am looking for.

Comment: Best answer I would say Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I would try doing it, using an imaginary pandas df with 3 columns consisting of your categorical variables and one column that is your target {cat1, cat2, cat3, target}:

```
predictors =df[["cat1", "cat2", "cat3"]]
target = df["target"]

from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

'''let sklearn do your training/testing split'''
pred_train, tar_train, pred_test, tar_test(predictors, target, test_size = .30)

'''create model with pre-pruning--play with the parameters consulting documentation'''
numtrees = 50
classifier=RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = numtrees,min_samples_leaf = 10,
                                  max_leaf_nodes = 25)
model=classifier.fit(pred_train,tar_train)
predictions=model.predict(pred_test)

'''To test the results'''
import sklearn.metrics

print '\n********* confusion matrix **********\n'
print "TRUE NEG   FALSE POS"
print '', sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix(tar_test,predictions)
print "FALSE NEG   TRUE POS"

print '\n============ Accuracy ============='
print sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score(tar_test, predictions)
```

[image]

[image]

Do keep in mind that I am not an experienced programmer--but the code above worked for me.